# AndEngine - How to handle onAreaTouched of a Sprite after adding it to a collection of sprites?

Tags: events, andengine, sprite

I have a collection of sprites in a `Map`

```
private Map<String, Sprite> sprite = new HashMap<String, Sprite>();
```

and all i need is to subscribe to their `onAreaTouched` event.

My attempt was something like this:

```
Sprite aSprite = new Sprite(i*128, 100, region.get("regionB"), context.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                                         final float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                                         final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                System.out.println(String.format("spriteB %fx%f", pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY()));
                return true;
            }
        };

scene.attachChild(aSprite);
scene.registerTouchArea(aSprite);
sprite.put("spriteB",aSprite);
```

What am i not doing right here and why my sprite doesn't respond to the touch event ?

Thanks.

## In the log i get this

```
06-10 15:11:51.598: V/AndEngine(1171): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
06-10 15:11:51.598: V/AndEngine(1171): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
```

and then a bunch of lines like this one

```
06-10 15:11:51.628: W/Trace(1171): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-10 15:11:51.688: W/Trace(1171): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-10 15:11:51.708: W/Trace(1171): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, you have correctly registered touch area(s) on the scene. If the touch event handler didn't get called, I don't think it is caused by your HashMap, the problem should come from other places. Did you override some touch related code in your scene or hud? For example, onSceneTouchEvent, onAreaTouchEvent, onSceneTouchListener...,etc?

Comment: i did not override them. i really don't get it :) all sprites apear at the cords i gave, but no touch event work.

Comment: I would suggest you trace code from onSceneTouchEvent() in Scene.java. Make sure it is called when touch events happened. Sprite's onAreaTouched() is dispatched in there too.

Comment: One thing you can try use direct instance of activity and then call getVertexBufferObjectManager() method on that. Don't use context.

Comment: with direct call of getVertexBufferObjectManager() in the activity instance it works, but when i pass activity as context it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "this" with "aSprite". You may need to declare "aSprite" globally on top of the class.

Replace:

```
this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
```

with this:

```
aSprite.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - aSprite.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - aSprite.getHeight() / 2);
```

**Edit:**

Try this approach, I hope this will work. Notice that I held the value of "i" inside "id" and made it final to use it inside the onAreaTouched() method. I think that is what you are looking for.

```
Sprite aSprite[] = new Sprite[spriteArrayLength];

for(i = 0; i < spriteArrayLength; i++){
    aSprite[i] = new Sprite(i*128, 100, region.get("regionB"), context.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
        private final int id = i;
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                                     final float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                                     final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            aSprite[id].setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - aSprite[id].getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - aSprite[id].getHeight() / 2);
            System.out.println(String.format("spriteB %fx%f", pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY()));
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Alright got the point, but how to make this approach to work with for(){Sprite aSprite = new Sprite(...){}} What i mean is that i generate multiple sprites, then collect them in that Map for later use, and also i need the touch event to work.